# xcode build setting group

Tags: xcode, xcode4, llvm, xcodebuild, build-settings

I'm using XCode4 to create some projects.

It seems that, different type of target comes with different configure group. 
Example for: If the target is `STL C++ Library` or `Cocoa Library`, there comes some config groups related with `Apple LLVM compiler 4.1`, and If target is `C/C++ Library`, there comes a bunch of `User-Defined` configures (most are related with g++).

But in the `Build Options` -> `Comipler for C/C++/Objective-C`, it is `Apple LLVM compiler 4.1`.

I think I must missing something, anybody can help ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to add some source files to your target and you'll get those options.
(Build Phases -> Compile Sources)